Scroll automático indesejado quando usar outros componentes com a Modal Bootstrap aberta
Estou tendo uma certa dificuldade com uma integração que estou fazendo em um sistema existente.
Possuo uma modal que a alimento com conteúdo via ajax, e a abertura da mesma faço via javascript, desativando o backdrop devido algumas limitações de outros códigos legados, inclusive o fechamento de click fora da modal:
var bsModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('modalEditar'), { backdrop: false });
 bsModal.show();

 $('.modal').on('click', function (event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('.modal-content').length) {
   $('#modalEditar').modal('hide');
  }
 });

Até aí tudo bem, antes de abrir eu alimento a modal com um formulário e um componente jquery chamado spectrum para abrir um seletor de cores.
Meu js que inicializa o mesmo:
let sncTools = {

 initializeSpectrum: () => {
      
  var colorPalette = [
    ['#f0f8ff', '#faebd7', '#7fffd4', '#d2691e', '#ff7f50'],
    ['#6495ed', '#fff8dc', '#dc143c', '#00ffff', '#00008b'],
    ['#008b8b', '#b8860b', '#a9a9a9', '#006400', '#bdb76b'],
    ['#8b008b', '#556b2f', '#ff8c00', '#9932cc', '#8b0000'],
    ['#e9967a', '#8fbc8f', '#483d8b', '#2f4f4f', '#00ced1']
  ];

  $('.spectrum').spectrum({
    allowEmpty: true,
    showInput: true,
    preferredFormat: "hex",
    showPalette: true,
    palette: colorPalette,
    change: function(color) {
      if (color) {
        $(this).val(color.toHexString());
      } else {
        $(this).val('');
      }
    },
    move: function(color) {
      if (color) {
        $(this).val(color.toHexString());
      } else {
        $(this).val('');
      }
    }        
  });


 }

}

Esse componente tem um conjunto de botões "Cancelar" e "Escolher", que fecha a caixa de cores, porém ao clicar em um destes, a modal do bootstrap aplica um foco automático no botão de fechar a modal. Experimentei marcar o botão como "disabled" e ai ele joga o focus no primeiro input da modal. Ou seja, ele procura o primeiro elemento ativo e aplica o focus.
Inicialmente achei que era um comportamento do Focus mas não é. Também criei um aside em tela cheia que fica a frente dessa modal, criei um botão simples pra fechar esse aside e tem o mesmo comportamento.
Abaixo uma imagem do componente spectrum. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como burlar esse comportamento? Imagino que seja do bootstrap, mas não achei nenhuma forma de impedir esse comportamento.


Através de muito debug, notei que aparentemente o que causa isso é o _handleFocusin, que fica no bootstra-bundle da versão 5.3. Porém mesmo tentando sobreescrever esse evento ele parece ser imutável.

No final das contas, tem um parâmetros que pode ser passado diretamente no HTML. Tentei via javascript e por algum motivo não aplicava.
Mas deixando o html com data-bs-focus="false" resolveu:
<div class="modal modal-xl fade" id="modalEditar" aria-labelledby="editModal" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-focus="false"></div>

